# Getting the min and max value from one field in database

Tags: sql

i have a table like this one:

```
idAluno    idUc       nota      final
110221045   bd        15          2
3           bd        13          2
110221045   algpg     10          2
110221045   EA11101   10          2
```

And another one like this

```
idUc             nome
 bd          Base de Dados
algpg          Álgebra
EA11101         Análise
```

How can i get the min and max value from the table nota like this:

```
  Nome            notaMax     notaMin
  Base de Dados      15          13
   Álgebra          10           10
   Análise          10           10
```

If somebody could help, i appreciate ! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say t1 = table 1 and t2 = table 2 - your select will then look like this:

```
select t2.nome,max(nota),min(nota) 
from t1,t2 where t2.iduc = t1.iduc 
group by t1.iduc;
```

Comment: The query is invalid, you would need to `group by t2.nome`, not `t1.iduc`. This query would be rejected by the DBMS. (you should also use proper explicit `JOIN`s, not the implicit ones in the where clause)

Comment: Works with mysql when grouping by t1.iduc - but not tested with any other db though.

Answer (score 0):

You should get along with something like this (dont know the name of your tables):

```
select Nome, min(nota) notaMin, max(nota) notaMax from table1, table2 where table1.idUc=table2.itUc;
```

As the downvote by someone else intends you should take a look at some kind of manual.

Answer (score 0):

First, we all start somewhere. Don't ever fear asking a question. I think Peter was really close.

```
select B.Nome,  max(A.nota) as notaMax, min(A.nota) as notaMin
from table1 A
inner join table2 B  on A.idUC=B.idUC
group by B.Nome
```

You can see int action [here in SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ca943/7)